# Selecting multiple values from a column and put them into separate columns

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a table like this:

```
MainUser | PartyUser
--------------------
George   | Tom
Michael  | Tim
Michael  | James
Michael  | Monica
Jim      | Nick
Jim      | Connie
```

And I need to get something like this:

```
MainUser | PartyUser1 | PartyUser2 | PartyUser3 | PartyUser4 ...
----------------------------------------------------------------
George   | Tom        |            |            |
Michael  | Tim        | James      | Monica     |
Jim      | Nick       | Connie     |            |
```

Can someone help to find a way doing this in sql?
I'm having a hard time figuring this out, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65786/query-pivot-multiple-columns-variable-number-of-rows) - seems to be a very similar problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I took a look over the question but the answer from irimias was closer to what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way (assuming you already know all the party users) would be to use [`pivot()`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) and [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en_us/library/ms186734.aspx) statements.

```
select  MainUser, 
        [1] as PartyUser1, 
        [2] as PartyUser2, 
        [3] as PartyUser3, 
        [4] as PartyUser4, 
        [5] as PartyUser5, 
        [6] as PartyUser6
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by MainUser order by PartyUser) as rn
    from party_table
    ) t
PIVOT (max(PartyUser) for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])) as u
```

Comment: Thank you! It is almost what I needed. I think I have to make some adjustments because sometimes it skips over some party users and sometimes it puts null values between party users.

Comment: It's ok now, I got it working. Thank you again!